# ionic 2 - save camera picture to javascript File Object for upload

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I want to create a javascript File Object of the picture i've just taken using Ionic (cordova) Native Camera Plugin for uploading.

```
Camera.getPicture().then(imageData => {
  let file = new File([???], 'filename', {type:'image/jpeg', lastModified:moment.now()})
})
```

I'm not sure what need to go into the first parameter to store the image to the file object.

Thanks!

Comment: can't you use [Camera.DestinationType](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_Camera.DestinationType) options to create a image file and get it's reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the camera options to return the base64 representation of the image, then convert this to a blob object and pass this in to the File constructor.

Or you could just use the camera plugin options to get the file's path then using the Cordova file plugin you can use the file reader to get the file entry and pass in the file that way.

Similar to this:

```
var cameraOptions = {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
};

function cameraSuccess(data){

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(data, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObject){

            var newFile = new File([fileObject], 'filename', {type:'image/jpeg', lastModified:moment.now()})

        }, fileFail);
    }, fileFail);

}

function fileFail(){

    //Handle file errors

}

navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
```

You would need to apply the above code to ionic but hopefully you get the idea.

Here is a link to the ionic file plugin documentation:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/